# how to get numeric dataframe value if boolean dataframe is True at position in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

We have two data frames one of boolean type and the other is numeric.
And I need to retrieve one of those values from d_num where d_bool is TRUE else NA.

is there any vectorize approach for this problem?

```
d_bool= data.frame(a = c(F,F,T,F,T),
                   b = c(F,F,F,F,T))

d_num = data.frame(a = c(1.0, 4.0, 2.0 ,4.1 ,6.8),
                   b = c(21.9 ,34.0 ,4.7 ,5.1 ,2.0))
```

**Required Output**

```
d= data.frame(a= c(NA,NA,2.0, NA,6.8),
              b= c(NA,NA,NA,NA,2.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just negate (`!`) the `d_bool` to convert the TRUE -> FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE and do the assignment

```
d_num[!(d_bool)] <- NA
```

-output

```
d_num
    a  b
1  NA NA
2  NA NA
3 2.0 NA
4  NA NA
5 6.8  2
```

---

Or we can do this on the fly

```
d <- (NA^!d_bool) * d_num
d
    a  b
1  NA NA
2  NA NA
3 2.0 NA
4  NA NA
5 6.8  2
```

Or with `replace`

```
replace(d_num, !d_bool, NA)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
d_num %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., !d_bool[[cur_column()]], NA)))
    a  b
1  NA NA
2  NA NA
3 2.0 NA
4  NA NA
5 6.8  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can negate the `d_bool` values and use it to subset `d_num` and assign `NA`.

```
d_num[!d_bool] <- NA

d_num
#    a  b
#1  NA NA
#2  NA NA
#3 2.0 NA
#4  NA NA
#5 6.8  2
```